# Batch normalize several video files using avisynth?

Tags: video, normalization, batch-processing, normalize, avisynth

My question is two parts.

Firstly I would like to normalize the audio of several video clips so that when played back to back the audio is relatively the same volume across all clips.  I'm not sure how to do this but I'm sure it's trivial.  I've seen the Normalize function but I want to normalize with reference to all other clips and not itself.  Thanks in advance for any help with this.

Secondly, and more importantly, I was wondering if there was a tool outside of scripting that will apply a single avisynth script across several clips.

Answer (score 0):

DDVideo Video to MP4 Gain can batch conversion and normalizer videos or musics files at the same sound level(from 75db to 105 db) without loss of original sound quality.it can resize or keep the original video size.very great and useful.